# Convergence of series of independent random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $(X_n)_{n=0}^{\infty} $ be a sequence of independent random variables. Suppose that $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} X_n $ converges a.s is it implies that there exist $K \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|X_n| < K~\forall n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't. Take, for example, $X_i$ such that $P(X_i = i) = 2^{-i}$, $P(X_i = 0) = 1 - 2^{-i}$. Then $\sum_i P(X_i \neq 0) = 2 < \infty$, so by Borel-Cantelli lemma with probability $1$ all but finitely many $X_i$ are equal to $1$ - thus series converges.